# HTML/CSS: Image with Background Image

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following image frame:

[image]

and now i have several images which all should have that frame as a background. If i for example have this image:

[image]

i want the result to be the following:

[image]

i want the background image frame always to have the same size (for example 300 * 400) and i want the picture for the frame to be centered inside the frame and i want the overhang to be cut off.

i set this css for the background:

```
.pola {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("../img/frames/frame_01.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

but i have no idea how to go on from here. How can i do that?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice. Maybe something like: `<div class="pola"><img src=".."></div>` when `.pola img{width:300px;height:400px;position:relative; top: 15px; left:15px;}`. Please notice that you'll have to play with the `top`,`left` props until it will fit the background.

Comment: tried border-image property? But it wont work with older browsers
 https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: good idea but i cant use it because the bottom border is like 50px and top, left, right 20px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, any image you put will fit inside parent `frame`.

```css
.pola {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4NJZ.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 486px;
  position: relative;
}
.pola img {
  width: 92%;
  height: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pola">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/sports/Dummy-Text/" />
</div>
```

Comment: its a nice solution but unfortunately the bottom border is too small. i need to show the complete frame.

Comment: @Mulgard You can adjust the height, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a similar layout by using a border and box-shadow around the image.

```css
.frame {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/500x300");
  background-position: -100px center;
  border-color: #e8e8e9;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 20px 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.pola {
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: url("../img/frames/frame_01.png") no-repeat fixed top center;
}
```

That is short way to write the code you already have. If you want the frame over the other image you would just put the the image after the frame url() like this:

```
.pola {
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: url("../img/frames/frame_01.png"), url("../img/this image is behind the frame") no-repeat fixed top center;
}
```

Hope this helps.